# What is the relation between syndetic subgroup and finitely index subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group. Subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called syndetic if there is compact set $K\subseteq G$ such that $G=KH$.

Gottschalk and   Hedlund ( in Topological Dynamics, P. 12) said that if $G$ is discrete and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is syndetic if and only if $H$ is finite index in $G$. I can not prove it.

Can some body help me to know proof it?
Thanks

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306223/what-is-the-relation-between-syndetic-subgroup-and-finite-index-subgroup

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $K$ is a compact set in a discrete group then $K$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks. If $G$ is not discrete, is it true that $H$ is syndetic subgroup if and only if it is finite index in $G$?

Comment: The above is posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306223/what-is-the-relation-between-syndetic-subgroup-and-finite-index-subgroup